# Network connection on Ubuntu 12.04: 20 seconds to load a web site

Tags: 12.04, networking

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell E6520 with Intel® Core™ i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4.
I use this version since the beta1. Without any troubles.
I have enabled all the update repository (also precise-proposed)
Recently, I don't remember from when, the network connection slowed down.
For example it take 20 seconds to load this web site: http://korben.info/

It's just incredibly slow. Resolving hostnames, getting the page and all his compound resources (images, scrips, ...) is slow.
It takes about 20 seconds to get the page loaded.
I have this issue using either a WiFi or a wired connection.

Thanks for your help,

/Etienne

$ lsb_release -rd
Description:  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:      12.04

$ uname -a
Linux xxxxxxxx 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here are the details of my network cards: (An extract of lshw)

```
    *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         produit: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
         fabriquant: Intel Corporation
         identifiant matériel: 19
         information bus: pci@0000:00:19.0
         nom logique: eth0
         version: 04
         numéro de série: d4:be:d9:1c:eb:61
         bits: 32 bits
         horloge: 33MHz
         fonctionnalités: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical
         configuration: broadcast=yes driver=e1000e latency=0 multicast=yes
         ressources: irq:20 mémoire:e2e00000-e2e1ffff mémoire:e2e80000-e2e80fff portE/S:4080(taille=32)

    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         produit: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
         fabriquant: Intel Corporation
         identifiant matériel: 1c.1
         information bus: pci@0000:00:1c.1
         version: b4
         bits: 32 bits
         horloge: 33MHz
         fonctionnalités: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         ressources: irq:17 mémoire:e2d00000-e2dfffff
       *-network
            description: Interface réseau sans fil
            produit: Centrino Advanced-N 6205
            fabriquant: Intel Corporation
            identifiant matériel: 0
            information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
            nom logique: wlan0
            version: 34
            numéro de série: 10:0b:a9:97:9a:d0
            bits: 64 bits
            horloge: 33MHz
            fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-24-generic firmware=17.168.5.3 build 42301 ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
            ressources: irq:46 mémoire:e2d00000-e2d01fff
```

Here is the google translate version:

```
    *-network
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
      manufacturer: Intel Corporation
      hardware ID: 19
      Bus information: pci @ 0000:00:19.0
      logical name: eth0
      Version: 04
      Serial Number: d4: be: d9: 1c: eb: 61
      bits: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical
      configuration: broadcast = yes driver = e1000e latency = 0 multicast = yes
      resources: irq: 20 memory: memory e2e00000-e2e1ffff: e2e80000-door e2e80fff / S: 4080 (size = 32)

 *-pci: 1
      description: PCI bridge
      Product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
      manufacturer: Intel Corporation
      hardware identifier: 1c.1
      Bus information: pci @ 0000:00:1 c.1
      Version: b4
      bits: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pci pm msi PCIExpress bus_master cap_list normal_decode
      configuration: driver = pcieport
      resources: irq: 17 memory: e2d00000-e2dfffff
    *-network
         description: Wireless Network Interface
         Product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205
         manufacturer: Intel Corporation
         hardware identifier: 0
         Bus information: pci @ 0000:02:00.0
         logical name: wlan0
         Version: 34
         serial: 10:0 b: a9: 97:9 a: d0
         bits: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical PCIExpress wireless
         configuration: broadcast = yes driver = iwlwifi driverversion = 3.2.0 firmware-24-generic ip = 17.168.5.3 build 42301 = 192.168.0.10 latency = 0 link = yes multicast = yes wireless = IEEE 802.11abgn
         resources: irq: 46 memory: e2d00000-e2d01fff
```

Comment: Try in terminal: `wget http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test` and update with how many seconds it takes.

Comment: 100%[=========================================================================================================================>] 104 857 600 1,64M/s   ds 61s

Comment: It took about 25 seconds to resolve cachefly.cachefly.net and then it downloaded in 61 seconds at the rate of 1,64 MB/s. The DNS configuration seems to have something to see with my slow web site loading.

Comment: Try `sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf` and then try the wget cachefly test again.

Comment: Incredible it works. Resolution is immediate. Web sites are loading fast. Problem fixed. Where do you think it comes from? Is there an issue that I may file?

Comment: @Etienne: You may be a victim of a poorly configured upstream nameserver. To use nameserver 8.8.8.8 permanently, either add a "dns-nameservers" line to /etc/network/interfaces (if you are using ifup) or enter the address 8.8.8.8 as a static nameserver address into NetworkManager (if you are using that) using the connection editor.

Comment: thaaaaaank you. I also had that problem and it repaired by using "sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf"

Answer (score 1):

My laptop was not working on my company network.
In order to fix this completely I did:

> sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install resolvconf

Don't know what was wrong the first time. Now its working fine.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably it would have sufficed to do "sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf".

Comment: Finally I found the root cause of the problem. Each time I use forticlientssl it resets the /etc/resolv.conf file by overriding it. This also removes the symbolic link. And yes I am able to fix it using "sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf".

Comment: You can restore the symlink more efficiently by doing "sudo ln -nsf ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf". After that you might have to run "resolvconf -u" to regenerate the target of the symlink. I just looked at forticlient.com and notice that the Linux version of their client isn't advertised. Doesn't give me confidence that their support for the Linux client is going to be very good.

Comment: I found the forticlient for linux [here](ftp://pftpintl:F0rt1intl@support.fortinet.com/FortiGate/v4.00/4.0MR3/MR3_Patch_6/SSL-VPN/). I agree there is no official support of the linux version. Thanks for your advice to repair the resolv.conf file.

Comment: I found this last build [here](ftp://pftpintl:F0rt1intl@support.fortinet.com/FortiGate/v4.00/4.0MR3/MR3_Patch_9/SSL-VPN/) that fixes the issue.